# How to execute Ant build in command line

Tags: ant, build, deferred-execution

I have an Ant build file, and I try to execute it in the command line with the following command:

```bat
$ C:\Program Files (x86)\.....>ant -f C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J\build.xml
```

But nothing happens, and the result is:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

My environment variable is correct.

What is the problem? Here is my build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
<project basedir="." default="build" name="iControlSilk4J">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../Program Files (x86)/Silk/SilkTest/eclipse"/>
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>
    <path id="Silk Test JTF 13.5.0 Library.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../Program Files (x86)/Silk/SilkTest/ng/JTF/silktest-jtf-nodeps.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="iControlSilk4J.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/apache-log4j.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/silktest-jtf-nodeps.jar"/>
        <path refid="Silk Test JTF 13.5.0 Library.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../Users/Admin/Desktop/java-mail-1.4.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../Users/Admin/Desktop/javax.activation.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/joda-time-2.3.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="iControlSilk4J.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>

...
```

Comment: Glad you pasted the build file in, but you omitted some important portions. Notice that the project tag has "build" as the default. To help you, we will need to see definition of the target named "build".

Comment: Is that what you talk about ?<project basedir="." default="build" name="iControlSilk4J"> ?!?

Comment: Yes, that indicates that the `build` target is the default.  Which means that somewhere in your build file, there is a `<target name="build"/>` tag we need to see.

Comment: Here is the definition of the target in the build.xml :

Comment: Here is the def. of the target in the build.xml : </target>
<target name="AdministrationCtrl.PlayDensite2Service">  I execute this command : ...>ant AdministrationCtrl.PlayDensite2Service -f res. is : Buildfile: C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J\build.xml
AdministrationCtrl.PlayDensite2Service:
[junit] Running com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Test com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl FAI
LED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second  But nothins execute ?!?

Comment: So the output is different now?  Looks like it is executing some junit tests which are not passing.

Comment: I remove lines with sub-project but still Failed.  My project is created with Silk4J.  I'm looking at the comment about Silk4J.

Answer (score 25):

Go to the Ant website and [download](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi). This way, you have a copy of Ant *outside* of Eclipse. I recommend to put it under the `C:\ant` directory. This way, it doesn't have any spaces in the directory names. In your System Control Panel, set the Environment Variable `ANT_HOME` to this directory, then pre-pend to the System `PATH`variable, `%ANT_HOME%\bin`. This way, you don't have to put in the whole directory name.

Assuming you did the above, try this:

```
C:\> cd \Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J
C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J> ant -d build
```

This will do several things:

- It will eliminate the possibility that the problem is with Eclipe's version of Ant.
- It is way easier to type
- Since you're executing the `build.xml` in the directory where it exists, you don't end up with the possibility that your Ant build can't locate a particular directory.

The `-d` will print out a lot of output, so you might want to capture it, or set your terminal buffer to something like `99999`, and run `cls` first to clear out the buffer. This way, you'll capture all of the output from the beginning in the terminal buffer.

Let's see how Ant should be executing. You didn't specify any targets to execute, so Ant should be taking the default `build` target. Here it is:

```
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
```

The `build` target does nothing itself. However, it *depends* upon two other targets, so these will be called first:

The first target is `build-subprojects`:

```
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
```

This does nothing at all. It doesn't even have a dependency.

The next target specified is `build-project` does have code:

```
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
```

This target does contain tasks, ***and*** some dependent targets. Before `build-project` executes, it will first run the `init` target:

```
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

This target creates a directory called `bin`, then copies all files under the `src` tree with the suffix `*.java` over to the `bin` directory. The `includeemptydirs` mean that directories without non-java code will not be created.

Ant uses a scheme to do minimal work. For example, if the `bin` directory is created, the `<mkdir/>` task is not executed. Also, if a file was previously copied, or there are no non-Java files in your `src` directory tree, the `<copy/>` task won't run. However, the `init` target will still be executed.

Next, we go back to our previous `build-project` target:

```
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="iControlSilk4J.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Look at this line:

```
<echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
```

That should have always executed. Did your output print:

```
[echo] iControlSilk4J: C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J\build.xml
```

Maybe you didn't realize that was from your build.

After that, it runs the `<javac/>` task. That is, if there's any files to actually compile. Again, Ant tries to avoid work it doesn't have to do. If all of the `*.java` files have previously been compiled, the `<javac/>` task won't execute.

And, that's the end of the build. Your build might not have done anything simply because there was nothing to do. You can try running the `clean` task, and then `build`:

```
C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J> ant -d clean build
```

However, Ant usually prints the target being executed. You should have seen this:

```
init:

build-subprojects:

build-projects:

    [echo] iControlSilk4J: C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J\build.xml

build:

Build Successful
```

Note that the targets are all printed out in order they're executed, and the tasks are printed out as they are executed. However, if there's nothing to compile, or nothing to copy, then you won't see these tasks being executed. Does this look like your output? If so, it could be there's nothing to do.

- If the `bin` directory already exists, `<mkdir/>` isn't going to execute.
- If there are no non-Java files in `src`, or they have already been copied into `bin`, the `<copy/>` task won't execute.
- If there are no Java file in your `src` directory, or they have already been compiled, the `<java/>` task won't run.

If you look at the output from the `-d` debug, you'll see Ant looking at a task, then explaining why a particular task wasn't executed. Plus, the debug option will explain how Ant decides what tasks to execute.

See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try running all targets individually to check that all are running correct

run ant target name to run a target individually

e.g. ant build-project

Also the default target you specified is

> project basedir="." default="build" name="iControlSilk4J"

This will only execute build-subprojects,build-project and init

Answer (score 0):

is it still actual?

As I can see you wrote `<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>`, then you wrote `<target name="build-subprojects"/>` (it does nothing). Could it be a reason?
Does this `<echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>` print appropriate message? If no then target is not running. 
Take a look at the next link http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=623277

Comment: Unfortunately, it's actual !  I know I'm near of the solution, but still...  I look in SQA Fotums and I try what it's propose but the build failed !

Comment: Here is the results : BUILD FAILED
Target "build.xml" does not exist in the project "iControlSilk4J".
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.tsort(Project.java:1912)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.topoSort(Project.java:1820)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.topoSort(Project.java:1783)

Comment: at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)

Comment: at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: like... project doesn't exists ?!?  <project basedir="." default="build" name="iControlSilk4J">  Why ?!?

Comment: "Target "build.xml" does not exist in the project "iControlSilk4J"" phrase only means that you run Ant typing "ant build.xml" and Ant can't find target named build.xml. You should run Ant just with command "ant". If you build file is named "build.xml" then just run Ant.

Comment: If I just type ant, the results is :Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J\build.xml  build:
    [junit] Running com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Test com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl FAILED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds  build:
    [junit] Running com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl

Comment: Time: 0 seconds  Why is it failed ?
I try ant -verbose and it gives me this error :  I try ant -verbose and it gives me this error :
<error message="Bad version number in .class file" number in .class file at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassnknown Source) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader.acces
<error message="Bad version number in .class file"

Comment: access$100(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)</error>

Comment: I try ant -debug and I get this error :  [junit] Couldn't find junit/framework/TestCase.class  What does it means ?  Maybe it's a missing piece ?!?  :-(

Comment: .....and at the end : The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
    [junit] Running com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Test com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl FAILED

Comment: I run ant -verbose and I get this :     [junit] 'crashfile=C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J\junitvmwatcher2522012376646798201.properties'
    [junit] 'propsfile=C:\Silk4J\Automation\iControlSilk4J\junit536763989337447728.properties'
    [junit]
    [junit] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [junit] not part of the command.
    [junit] Running com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Test com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl FAILED

Comment: why it gives crash at junitwatcher2522...  ?!?  Is it the cause ?!?

Comment: I found there's a version problem.  I resolve this one but now, I have this error :  <error message="org/apache/log4j/Logger" type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger at com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl.<clinit>(AdministrationCtrl.java:41) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at

Comment: ....java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)</error> 
What does it mean ?